# Expression from Access not showing proper in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, pivot-table

First I want to say that I really did try to solve this first. Scoured the boards and phoned a friend (no luck).

Here is my problem, hoping someone can help.

Problem: I need to create a field in the data that displays the value HOME or AWAY based on a string of characters found in 1 of 10 other fields. The express I created in Access work perfectly when I view the query in table view in Access. However when I import that data from Access to Excel the only value that displays is HOME.

DataBase: MS SQL Server 2016 (latest version + patches)

Queries: MS Access 2013

Goal: pull the data into Excel 2013 to produce easy to read and manipulate Excel Pivot tables (execs like this)

```
HOME AWAY: IIf([Trailer 1] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 2] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 3] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 4] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 5] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 6] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 7] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 8] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 9] Like "*TAP*","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 10] Like "*TAP*","AWAY","HOME"))))))))))
```

I have re-written the above formula about 6 different ways and the result is always the same in Access in shows the value HOME or AWAY properly if any of the 10 trailers contains the string TAP. As soon as I import into a Pivot table into Excel the only value that comes across is HOME.

My calculated numeric expressions come across without any issues at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you have a query in Access that displays the correct results? Then import the results to Excel; http://www.excelandaccess.com/how-to-import-access-data-to-excel-using-the-get-external-data-from-access-option/

Comment: Please show the Excel vba connection making the call. Do you connect Excel to Access or SQL Server?.

Comment: @Absinthe this precisely what I am doing

Comment: @Parfait I connect excel to access and access  has linked tables to the SQL server. Where can I find the vba connection? The method I am using to connect to the access query is the method Absinthe outlined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are connecting to MS Access via ODBC (not through MSAccess.EXE GUI application) by way of the Excel GUI ribbon option - *External Data* module, the `LIKE` wildcard must use `%` and not `*`. Percent is the ANSI-92 SQL wildcard and asterisk being the ANSI-89 wildcard. See official [MSO documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1) on this issue.

This is the reason no data is returned as the `LIKE` expression is looking literally for an asterisk in string column. Consider re-writing query which will return *HOME* only in MS Access since by default Access .mdb/.accdb files uses ANSI-89, most likely to be backwards-compatible with prior releases.

```sql
HOME AWAY: IIf([Trailer 1] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 2] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 3] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 4] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 5] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 6] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 7] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 8] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 9] Like "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 10] Like "%TAP%","AWAY","HOME"))))))))))
```

---

There are two ways to make the same query compatible in both Excel and Access using `LIKE`.

**Database Settings**

Per above MS link, set MS Access to use SQL Server ANSI 92 syntax. Specifically, under File \ Options \ Object Designers, check under *SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)* the *This Database* checkbox. Once you do, the percent wildcard must be used in queries running `LIKE`.

**ALike Operator**

Use the `ALike` operator with `%` wildcard with no change to default settings.

```sql
HOME AWAY: IIf([Trailer 1] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 2] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 3] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 4] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 5] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 6] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 7] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 8] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 9] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY",
IIF ([TRAILER 10] ALike "%TAP%","AWAY","HOME"))))))))))
```